# How to solve the problem when the circuit depth and width are deepened during qiskit simulation

Tags: qiskit

[image]

Simulation failed and returned the following error message:
ERROR: a circuit requires more memory than max_memory_mb.
Traceback (most recent call last):
Input In [5] in <cell line: 4>
counts = result_sim.get_counts(QC)
File /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit/result/result.py:280 in get_counts
exp = self._get_experiment(key)
File /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit/result/result.py:391 in _get_experiment
raise QiskitError('Data for experiment "%s" could not be found.' % key)
QiskitError: 'Data for experiment "circuit-3" could not be found.'

Use %tb to get the full traceback.

Comment: can you share your circuit?
we need to see your circuit

Comment: I found similar issue https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/16946/20884